# Understanding Quotas for Google API

Tags: google-api, google-plus, quotas

I'm currently integrate Google+ API to my service.
I'd like to know what's the limitation for this kind of api:
https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/{user_id}/activities/public

in google develop console, I found this:
Quota summary

```
Free quota  10,000 requests/day
Remaining   9,998 requests/day
            99.98% of total
Per-user limit  
5 requests/second/user
```

I think there will be two kind of limitation:

1. Application level

   For example, how many requests can an app send per day(sum of the number for all users), and what's the max qps?
2. User level

   For example, how many requests can an app send per day for a special user, and what's the max qps?

But I can't find the exactly info, does anyone know?

Answer (score 0):

Can't say particularly about this API, but when I used Google Places api the quota was linked with IP address.
So if it expired, we need to use different IP for hit.
No user / application quota.

Comment: this does  not answer the question

Answer (score 0):

you already have those answers in your question:

10,000 requests per day in total, using that developer console key, thus your total "app" calls.

per user there is no limit, there is a rate quota. a single user could at most make 5*(seconds in a day) requests per day.

in this specific api case this is much bigger than 10,000 thus that rate quota is not that useful (except it prevents users from quickly depeting the 10,000 daily quota).

you can edit that rate quota so its lower or higher, and is used so a single user cant consume all the app quota (maliciously or otherwise)

Comment: 10,000 requests for an app is so small, assume an app has 100,000 users, then each user even can't have one request per day. Definitely need to increase this number.

Comment: indeed some google apis are like that while others (like drive api) give you millions daily. some allow you to ask google to increase the quota. i also use that api (sparingly) and google increased mine to 50k by sending then a single email explaining my use case.